# Regex optimization for Full Name

Tags: regex, angular6

**Problem:** Input field takes too much time to validate the input.

**Reason for delay:** Regex validation takes time when there are two consecutive spaces.

**Regex:**

```
'^(([A-Za-z]+[\-\' ]?)*([A-Za-z]+)?)+([A-Za-z]+[\-\' ]?)*([A-Za-z]+)?$'
```

The regex allows aphostrophe(') and infinite number of words as long as `maxLength` of input `< 128`

**Error:**

> [Violation] 'input' handler took 26713ms

Comment: Are you trying to create something like `"^(?!.{129})[A-Za-z]+(?:[-' ][A-Za-z]+)*$"`?

Comment: Can you give examples of input and expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have nested repetition that cause [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html):

```
([A-Za-z]+[\-\' ]?)*
```

Instead you can use [unrolling the loop technique](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop):

```
[A-Za-z]+([\-\' ][A-Za-z]+)*
```

I've written a detailed explanation of a similar example in [this blogpost](https://medium.com/textmaster-engineering/performance-of-regular-expressions-81371f569698)

Another nested repetition is in:

```
(([A-Za-z]+[\-\' ]?)*([A-Za-z]+)?)+
```

you can use similar technique to optimize it.